# Learning stochastic calculus, want to know what the notation of this function means

Tags: stochastic-processes

$f(x) = \sum_if_i 1_{[ai;bi)}(x)$

This is a function that is piecewise constant equal to f_i on finite set of intervals [ai; bi) in a set F:

I am a little confused about what this 1 in the summation means. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suspect $1_{[a_i,b_i)}$ is the function which is one on the interval $[a_i,b_i)$ and zero elsewhere.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense! thank you!